# Flip-Animation for Activity-Change

Tags: android, android-activity

i want to flip between two activities like the iPhone.

I tried to use the overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim) Method, but was not successful.

Has someone implemented an animation like this?

fesp

Comment: If you want to switch between only two activities, try `ViewFlipper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have to change Activities, first start the desired layout animation on the outmost view (possibly a viewgroup) of the current Activity. When the animation finished, start the new Activity. Also, remember to switch off the default Activity transition animation.

Comment: Well, thats the right way. Thank u very much! I also found a nice link http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html