# Flip like animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, flip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flip-Animation for Activity-Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473467/flip-animation-for-activity-change)

I'm new to *Android Animation*.

I wanted to implement flip like animation when making transition from one activity to another.
 **Note** that I'm not talking about page flip animation, rather the activity should turn from right to left from back side.

I might not be clear in the question, provide your suggestion.

I implemented `fade-in` , `fade-out` by using `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);` but don't have an idea whether flip can be done in same way.

Comment: See this similar question :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473467/flip-animation-for-activity-change

Comment: I'm not able to get the answer posted in that link. Can u dig in a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, [android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher](http://blog.robert-heim.de/karriere/android-startactivity-rotate-3d-animation-activityswitcher/)

This example makes use of animation in and animation out, such that it will look like a 3d flip taking place between activities. In the first activity's onResume you will be able to see a "animation out" followed by "animation in" in Activity two.

Comment: while trying to implement according to above link, I get this error : `Flip3dAnimation cannot be resolved to a type`. Is there any dependency?

Comment: `Flip3dAnimation` is not getting recognized. to which package it belongs?